# Consistent estimator for Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, parameter-estimation

I want to prove that for $S_n=1/n\sum_{i=1}^n1_{\{X_i=0\}}$, $\log(1/S_n)$ is a consistent estimator for $\lambda$ where $P(X_i=k)=\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}/k!$ so Poisson distributed. Anyone have an idea?

I was thinking using Markov's inequality. I want to prove that $P(\log(1/S_n)-\lambda>0)\to0$. Therefore
$$P(\log(1/S_n)-\lambda>0)=P(\log(1/S_n)>\lambda)=P(1/S_n>e^\lambda)\le\frac{E(1/S_n)}{e^\lambda}$$
by the inequality. However I can't prove the last term goes to zero.

Comment: Can you find the distribution of $1_{\{X_i=0\}}$? And of $S_n$?

Comment: I was thinking using Markov inequality: I want to prove that $P(log(1/S_n)-\lambda>0) \rightarrow 0$ Therefore $P(log(1/S_n)-\lambda>0)=P(log(1/S_n)>\lambda)=P(1/S_n>eˆ\lambda)\leq E(1/S_n)/eˆ\lambda)$ by Markov. However I can't prove the last tern goes to zero.

Comment: One rarely meets consistent estimators $\theta_n$ of some parameter $\theta$ such that $P(\theta_n-\theta>0)\to0$... so, one wonders why you embarked on such a task. What would be a more reasonable statement to prove, according to your notes and/or to the examples of estimation consistency you know?

Answer (score 0):

1. Due to the law of large numbers, your $S_n$ converges in probability to $P(X_1=0)=e^{-\lambda}$.
2. Since $\log$ is a continuous function, $\log S_n$ converges in probability to $\log P(X_1=0)$ and you're done!